# Call dynamically a function using plpgsql

Tags: plpgsql

I create a function that returns the value of a field when the id is given :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dcteam(id int) RETURNS text
AS $$
#print_strict_params on
DECLARE
dc_team text;
BEGIN
    SELECT monitoring_table.dc_team INTO STRICT dc_team
        FROM monitoring_table WHERE monitoring_table.id = get_dcteam.id;
    RETURN dc_team;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I call it this way :

```
select * from get_dcteam((select id from monitoring_table where id=30))
```

What I want to do is call the function  dynamically. I don't want to precise a known id(given value in parameter) but any existing value in my table. The result of this query I will use it in a trigger. 
I'm a newbie and I'm struggling to learn dynamic SQL.
Your help would be precious. 
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever call it like that. Because it returns a single value (`RETURNS text`) Call it like this instead, it's cleaner.

```
SELECT id, get_dcteam(id)
FROM monitoring_table
WHERE id = 30;
```

Now if you want it for more id's remove the WHERE Clause.

```
SELECT id, get_dcteam(id)
FROM monitoring_table;
```

Also you should probably rewrite that to use regular SQL, as it may be inlined.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dcteam(id int)
RETURNS text
AS $$
    SELECT monitoring_table.dc_team
    FROM monitoring_table
    WHERE monitoring_table.id = get_dcteam.id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

But one step further, I'd just delete the function entirely. It's basic SQL and it's just going to slow you down. Look at what you're doing: `get_dcteam` is querying `monitoring_table`, and you're calling it on a query that is already visiting that table! This will be much faster and clearer:

```
SELECT id, dc_team
FROM monitoring_table
WHERE id = 30;
```

Having previously [answered this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259181/get-dynamically-value-of-a-column-using-plpgsql/259183#259183) you said

> thanks for your answer. This call will give me several rows. What I Want is use this function in a where clause of an other one, but without passing the id in parameters. – zakaria mouqcit 3 hours ago

I'm not even sure what that means. Perhaps you could explain.

Comment: Okay, This function would be called in an other one in a where clause. As previously explained the result of the function is a text which depends on a given id passed on parameters, yet what I want to do is call it dynamically, it means that the id won't have a known value (id=30) for instance, but  any given id by the user , the function should search for it and return  the team which match it.

Comment: I'm not sure why *any* of that matters. You can still supply an ID given my calling syntax.

Comment: I solved the problem in an other way.Thanks for getting involved with me to solve my issue